# MainForm access method from another form

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to transform WinForm to WPF as follow code:

Login form:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public static XmppClientConnection getXmpp()
{
    return xmppCon;
}
```

MainForm:

```
public partial class MainForm: Form
{
    XmppClientConnection xmppCon = Login.getXmpp(); // It's okay to access
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

WPF Code:

```
public partial class MainForm: Form
{
    XmppClientConnection xmppCon = Login.getXmpp(); // my Login can not access getXmpp method;
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Error with `Login.getXmpp` at line: `XmppClientConnection xmppCon = Login.getXmpp();`

My question is, why MainForm can't access method getXmpp from Login form?

Comment: Is the visibility of Login.getXmpp() internal?

Comment: MainForm.xaml and Login.xaml in the same root of App

Comment: Can you post the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

You WPF code is the same as your winforms code so I think you've pasted in the wrong info there. It's possible they have a different namespace or are in different projects?

Comment: But, I checked already, it's the same namespace and the same project!

Answer (score 0):

The method getXmpp is not defined within the Login class.